# list all the information of a process under commandline in osx or linux

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, process

Is there any command to list all the information associated with a process, include all parameters in PS command, open files and ports and so on? 
Thanks!

Comment: What OS is this on ?

Comment: OSX. linux is OK.

Comment: To get _all the information associated with a process_ I'd have a look at the various files in `/proc/PID_OF_PROCESS`. At least under Linux, on OSX I think there is no proc-Filesystem?!

Comment: Please clarify, OSX and Linux are different systems, which one are you using? What do you mean by "all information"? Could you give an example of your desired output? Do you want to know how much memory, which memory addresses are in use, what CLI options were passed, how long it has been running for?